# Fragment mesh based on texture

Tags: modifiers, particles, texture-painting, geometry-nodes

I'm looking for the best pipeline to obtain an effect similar to the first image I posted here. The artist (Matthew Stone) did this with Zbrush apparently. [image: artwork by Matthew Stone]
I'm using a Human Generator mesh to work on and I got to the point where I managed to texture paint the intended brush work and experienced with the explode modifier to fragment the mesh randomly.[image] But I need to be able to control the shape of the fragments based on the texture so I can explode defined brush trace shapes. Is there a way to do this without having to create separate objects manually? For example be able to select the exact shape based on the texture and explode only those selected parts ? Or use some geometry nodes to obtain this effect? Can anyone suggest any process that would be appropriate to experiment with? Or maybe someone can suggest a better approach that doesn't freeze blender? (I'm on Windows 11, 32 Gb Ram, I7 processor, 500 gb SD but quite full on C)

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should first explode your mesh, then paint on the fractured cells, not the other way around. I don't see how you could easily tell Blender how to fracture the cells depending on the brush strokes. In the artwork you showed there are at most 10 shapes that look like they have been exploded. I think the artist created those shapes and painted over them, not the other way round. My 2 cents

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too but what I want to obtain is also the impression that certain brushstrokes are thicker than the rest of the mesh but stay closer to the mesh. Let’s say a partial displacement that apply only on selected areas but the “ displaced” parts to have only a slight thickness and look like they are partly separated. Kind of like they just start to peel from one end but still attached on another…I’m pretty certain there must be a way. It’s just deeply buried in Blender’s intricacies.